# Android Account Type for Microsoft Exchange Active Sync

Tags: android, exchange-server, account, accountmanager

I have an issue that I have an account type on a phone, and I do not know the string that represents it. e.g com.google for gmail etc

I think the account type may be Microsoft Exchange Active Sync. Does anyone know the account string for that?

Update - It has been confirmed their accounts have been set up as Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync. Does anyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the Android code base I found the account type for Microsoft Exchange Active Sync is `com.android.exchange`